# How to use $_GET in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

here is a url of my website, this url is used to call the post from database which its id=1

http://***.com/?view=entry&id=1

i try in the model with this code

```
<?php
class inner_query extends CI_Model{
    // main shakli wow in slider 
    function get_current_entry(){
        $q= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM hs_categories_cat INNER JOIN hs_news_nw ON id_cat=idcat_nw WHERE active_nw='1' AND id_nw={$id}");
        if($q->num_rows() == 1){
            foreach($q->result() as $row){
                $data[]=$row;//new array to store every results returned from database 
            }
            return $data;//return with array results
        }
    }
}
```

**and here is my controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class entry extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        //load model of the current entry
        $this->load->model('inner_query');
        $data['get_current_entry'] = $this->inner_query->get_current_entry();

        $this->load->view('inner_page.php', $data);
    }

}
```

**once check this page i get this error message**

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

SELECT * FROM hs_categories_cat INNER JOIN hs_news_nw ON id_cat=idcat_nw WHERE active_nw='1' AND id_nw=

Filename: E:***\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing `$id` to your `get_current_entry()` function.

In your controller, pass `$id` to your model like so:

```
$data['get_current_entry'] = $this->inner_query->get_current_entry($id);
```

Modify your model's `get_current_entry()` function to accept `$id` as a parameter:

```
function get_current_entry($id){
    // other code here...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the `$id` to `get_current_entry()` function in your controller. How is it supposed to get that value?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't passed $id down into the functions. You define it in your `index()` method, but it's not passed down via object attributes or method arguments to your get_current_entry() method, so the sql query will insert a null variable into the string, making the query be:

```
...WHERE active_nw='1' AND id_nw=
```

causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the uri with query string, you must enable query string in your application/config.php for more info see: [CodeIgniter URLs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

Also you have option

> $config['allow_get_array']        = TRUE;
>   which is TRUE by default in the latest version of CI. This option permits you to use the $_GET[] array.

The other way (better) is to use url like : http://example.com/view/entry/1 and get id by

> $this->uri->segment($n);
>   where $n = 3 in the example.

Answer (score 0):

By default, CI unsets $_GET, so you can use `$CI->uri->segment_array();`
Also, here is a nice example on how you can create a helper function that replaces $_GET:

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/alternative_to_GET